# Access is denied, with Gstreamer audio capture on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2022, audio

*Note: I'm posting to ServerFault with this as I believe there's some sort of permissions or isolation or perhaps missing system component needed specifically for Windows Server.  This is not a general Gstreamer or audio/video question.*

---

I have a sound card installed on Windows Server 2022 Standard, and am able to play audio using a web browser.  I can even capture audio with FFmpeg via DirectShow.

For a new project, I need to capture audio via Gstreamer.  Unfortunately, this isn't working.  A very simple command fails:

```perl
gst-launch-1.0 wasapisrc use-audioclient3=true ! fakesink
```

```
0:00:00.270717000  4768 000002432EE168C0 INFO                  wasapi gstwasapiutil.c:1017:gst_wasapi_util_initialize_audioclient3:<wasapisrc0> Using IAudioClient3, default period 480 frames, fundamental period 480 frames, minimum period 480 frames, maximum period 480 frames
0:00:00.279814000  4768 000002432EE168C0 ERROR                 wasapi gstwasapiutil.c:1032:gst_wasapi_util_initialize_audioclient3:<wasapisrc0> IAudioClient3::InitializeSharedAudioStream failed (80070005): Access is denied.
```

`0x80070005`, access denied.

Assuming this was a problem with the WASAPI module, I've tried its other modes, turning off AudioClient3, switching to the WASAPI2 Gstreamer module.  I even tested the DirectShow module... one would think this would work since DirectShow works in FFmpeg, however, I get similar error messages that access is denied.

I've even tried the stupid thing of running Gstreamer as Administrator.  No luck.

I should note that all of these commands I tried work fine with the exact same binaries under Windows 11 Pro, with the exact same sound card driver.  This is leads me to believe there's some sort of default policy that's blocking Gstreamer from accessing the sound card.

How can I further narrow down this problem and solve it?  Any ideas are most welcome.  Thanks!